# Why does encryption doesn't work/apply to access device storage or Google photos or drive when we upload a file from device/cloud to any webpage/apps

Tags: security, internal-storage, encryption, file-management, file-permissions

Example : YouTube, Facebook, Instagram, Chrome ( any app )
If I'm accessing YouTube or any other app where I can upload content from Android device with or without the app lock features, whenever I click on add file, it doesn't ask for gallery password even though I have my phone's gallery encrypted with app lock, infact, in some apps even the hidden files also appear. What's the point of having app lock if anyone can access all the files through any other app's upload feature ? Does Android not provide any security or encryption facility to access  device storage when accessing it (storage) through a third-party app? Anybody can access Google photos, drive storage etc without any password if they have access to the device, doesn't matter whether the apps are password protected or not.
To explain further , in this case let's say my Chrome isn't password protected, if anyone has access to my device's Chrome browser, they can access all of my content from Google photos, drive, phone's storage etc just by using any webpage's upload file feature. What's the point of keeping password pr applock to gallery / or Google storage if they're acceible like that?
Faced this issue is most Android devices ( Redmi note 5 pro, Samsung devices, Nokia, oppo, vivo etc.)

Comment: Isn't it already visible in the app name "applock"? It locks apps not files. A more fine granulated access system to files on the sd-card section was introduced with Android 10/11 - it is named scoped storage.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check for the existence of files without root privileges](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241268/check-for-the-existence-of-files-without-root-privileges)