# Check for the existence of files without root privileges

Tags: applications, root-access, security, privacy, system

How do apps check for the existence of files and folders on /data and /system partitions without having root privileges?
I know some games and apps do this for anticheat and security reasons.

Comment: /system is world readable and /data is accessable within it's own uid

Comment: Thanks. Explain the /data part, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507)

Comment: Not really, still not clear on exactly how an app can detect the existence of another apps directory under /data/data for instance. I know apps can access their own data/data/"package name" but I don't know how it can find the presence of another app directory.

Comment: existence of apps is not existence of files and directories. there exist (pm) package manager and other APIs for this (java stuff). wait for someone other will explain better

Comment: Not the existence of apps, I specifically said app directory but it can be any directory so long as it's under /data

Comment: If your question is about apps can read files or directories of other apps (in /data) the answer is NO

Comment: Apps can NOT detect the existence of other apps' directories under `/data/data/` without root. Discretionary Access Control doesn't allow different UIDs (apps) to access each other's data. See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218572/218526), [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218374/218526) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526) how Android's app sandboxing works.

Comment: There's on exception though. On old Android releases or with SELinux permissive, an app can detect the existence of other app's root directory i.e. `/data/data/com.xyz`. But it's not possible to read its contents.

Comment: How do they do this?

Comment: They (the apps) don't play any magic in this. It's just permitted by the operating system. So any app can do this. Read about Discretionary (file owner, group, mode) and Mandatory (SELinux) Access Controls to know how it works.

Comment: @IrfanLatif How is "old" defined for Android releases in the context of your comment?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket old is when Android didn't use SELinux [MLS](https://selinuxproject.org/page/NB_MLS) to enforce individual SELinux sandboxes on a per-app basis. As [briefly mentioned in official documatation](https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox#protections) it started with Pie. You can check AOSP git log to find when exactly the changes were made.